# Passing functions by reference - how to get the address?

Tags: c++

newbie at c++ and learning for fun. I'm still trying to understand references and dereferencing syntax, so if you're reading this, have a heart and please help explain if you can. Generally I understand that `=& foo` returns a reference to the object `foo`. And that a reference, by `&foo`, should be able to be reveal the address of the object it refers to just as a pointer would. So this works to redeem the address of foo:

```
//EXAMPLE 1 - works as expected?
void useFooRef(int &foo) {    
    cout << "using foo @ " << &foo << endl; //using foo @ 0x16eebb4e8
    //no warning here!
}

int foo = 1;

int main() {
    useFooRef(foo);
    return (0);
}
```

But if `foo` is a function I'm passing, it seems fine to receive it as a pointer and extract its address; nonetheless I've read that it's safer to pass by reference to avoid passing null pointers. But if I do that, I get a compiler warning...

```
//EXAMPLE 2
void useFooPtr(int (*foo)()) {
    cout << "using foo @ " << &foo << endl; //using foo @ 0x16fb634c8
    //no warning here!
};

void useFooRef(int (&foo)()) {
    cout << "using foo @ " << &foo << endl; //using foo @ 1
    //warning: reference cannot be bound to dereferenced null pointer in well-defined C++ code
};

int foo() {
    return (3);
};

int main() {
    useFooPtr(foo);
    useFooRef(foo);
    return (0);
}
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around what is being passed, like: The mental map I have of c++ right now is that a variable name contains some metadata as to its own memory slot, and a reference contains the memory slot of what it refers to, and a pointer contains its own memory slot, which holds the slot of the thing it points to. What would this metadata look like that's different when a function receives a reference vs. a pointer in the case of a function being passed, and why is it possible to extract the memory address using `&foo` when it's a simple int passed as reference in example 1, but not when it's a function passed as reference in example 2... even though the address of `foo` *can* be extracted in both cases if it's received as a pointer?

Comment: I get other errors: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout' and error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'.

Comment: sorry, didn't include the top of the code in my example `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`

Comment: The e.1: *no warning here!* it's not true: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: Apologies, that int definition slipped in because I'm summarizing and simplifying into this post. I've changed it to void. Originally I was playing with this in a function that returned an int. Also, okay, I saw your top thread about not `using namespace std;` but for the sake of brevity and as I'm just trying to create simple tests to further my own understanding the language, I'm using it and omitting it from these examples. I'm trying to understand the concept of why f((&fn)(args)) is throwing a warning when trying to retrieve the &fn address later, whereas f((*fn)(args)) or f(&int) isn't.

Comment: @joshstrike Try [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) which saves you from these issue. Your example code should compile and run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::cout::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) does not have an overloaded version for `int (*foo)()`, thus it uses `std::cout::operator<<(bool)` and outputs

```
std::cout << static_cast<bool>(&foo)  // 0 or 1.
```

> warning: reference cannot be bound to dereferenced null pointer in well-defined C++ code

It's not a full warning text. Honestly, reading not a complete warning is a bad habit leading to failed study. The complete warning text is pretty clear:

> warning: reference cannot be bound to dereferenced null pointer in well-defined C++ code; **pointer may be assumed to always convert to true** [-Wundefined-bool-conversion]

It's well known that a reference is an alias of an existing object and its address may not be `nullptr`. The compiler warns you that it will always output `1`. GCC also raises a precise warning:

> warning: the compiler can assume that the address of 'foo' will never be NULL [-Waddress]

```
void useFooPtr(int (*foo)()) {
    cout << "using foo @ " << &foo << endl; //using foo @ 0x16fb634c8
    //no warning here!
};
```

`foo @ 0x16fb634c8` - here you output the address of the local variable `foo`. The function address is output by `std::cout << foo`, and it also will output `foo @ 1`.

If you want to output the address of the function, cast it to `void*`

```
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(foo)
```

Comment: ahahha! Thank you. This tells me a lot of things. In hindsight it makes sense that `&foo` from `(int (*foo)())` would be a local pointer's address. I also didn't interpret the warning as meaning it was always safe - I thought it was saying I had the code was poorly defined. (It would have been nicer if it mentioned that std::cout didn't have a matching signature but that yes it was always safe). Marking this answer correct. But by the way, do you consider this passing a reference the preferred method over passing a pointer?

Comment: note that casting function pointer to `void*` is not guaranteed to compile.  To portably "output" a function pointer you've got to alias it as byte array

Comment: @M.M this kind of re-raises my other question - is there something fundamental about function pointers that's different from any other pointer? Are they traveling with "metadata" or something that can't be interpreted as easily as another address?

Comment: Why does the `void *` return a different address?; it also seems that depending on the clang version  it can also be a shorter address, in dogbolt with 14 gives `0x7ffc75759100` and `0x4014e0`.

Comment: @SrPanda my understanding on this (so far) is just that std::cout defaults to casting any function pointer to bool - and therefore to 1 if it exists. That seems to check out (I tested it by just making a pointer to the function inside `main()` and trying to std::cout, and the same casting to void* worked). But as @M.M. said, maybe it doesn't work all the time and I'm not sure why that would be the case.

Comment: @joshstrike the standard doesn't require function pointers to be "interchangeable" with object pointers. In general platforms might represent the two very differently